# Unzip files using ftp and java

Tags: java, ftp, zip

I want to upload a zip file to the server using `FTP` protocol. 
1. What is the best way to zip my files using java? 
2. Later on I want to unzip the file in the **server**. How can I do it with `FTP` and `java`? 

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GZipStream` classes ([GZipOutputStream](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) and [GZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html)) should take care of the compression part. You can take a look [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.zip/CompressFile.html) to see how you can compress files and [this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.zip/UncompressFile.html) tutorial to uncompress the file. To upload the file through the use of FTP you can use Apache's [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

Comment: I tried to use `FTPClient`, but there is no way to **unzip** the **zip** file when it's on the **server**.

Comment: @choop: What do you mean exactly? You need to have access to the server to unzip it. The assumption is that you have a client which zips and uploads through FTP and some code running on the server which reads and unzips.

Comment: Using `FTPClient` class allow to create and delete files. 
For example: FTPClient.deleteFile.      I want the same way to unzip my file.

Comment: @choop: If you go through my answer I never said that `FTPClient` takes care of zipping/unzipping. I posted two links for two tutorials, please go through my answer again

Comment: OK. But there is a way to unzip a file in the server using a class like `FTPClient` that unzip files?

Comment: @choop: To my knowledge no, but you can always search.

Answer (score 1):

You can create zip file using `ZIPOutputStream` that is supported in Java.

take a look at here 
http://www.java-examples.com/create-zip-file-directory-using-zipoutputstream-example

Later on once you uploaded the file, you can unzip it using `ZIPInputStream`.

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/334.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, But how can I **Unzip** the zip in the server using `FTP` and `java`?

Comment: @choop,when your server want to unzip the file?

Comment: **After** the zipped file will upload to the server. I want to Unzip it.

Comment: you create an outputstream and write like this:while((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0)
                                        {
                                           zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                                        }

Comment: Then, on server you create a GZIPInputstream with your FTP server input stream, ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(ftpserverInputstream));

Answer (score 0):

FTPClient in Appache Commons can help you in dealing with ftp. For zipping have a look at java.util.zip. I have used Zip I\O classes and found very easy to use